# Why isn’t my custom UITableView cell showing?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

I’ve implemented a custom cell for a UITableView, but when I run the Playground it’s just a standard table. It’s probably something stupid simple, but I’m very new to UIKit and somewhat new to Swift.

Also, I’ve tried to implement a “sticky header”, but no matter what I try the header scrolls with the rest of the table.

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport



class ViewController : UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 19
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell: CardCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CardCell", for: indexPath) as! CardCell
        cell.messageLabel.text = "yo"
        return cell
    }


    var convoTableView = UITableView()

    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()

        convoTableView = UITableView(frame: self.view.bounds, style:
            UITableView.Style.plain)
        convoTableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        convoTableView.register(CardCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CardCell")
        let header = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: convoTableView.frame.width, height: 100))
        header.backgroundColor = .red

        self.convoTableView.delegate = self
        self.convoTableView.dataSource = self

        let yourLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
        yourLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
        yourLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        yourLabel.text = "mylabel text"

        header.addSubview(yourLabel)

        convoTableView.tableHeaderView = header
        convoTableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 40.0

        self.view.addSubview(convoTableView)
    }




}


class CardCell: UITableViewCell {


    let messageLabel:UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
        label.clipsToBounds = true
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()

    let dateLabel:UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 8)
        label.clipsToBounds = true
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()

    let containerView:UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.clipsToBounds = true
        return view
    }()

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        containerView.addSubview(messageLabel)
        containerView.addSubview(dateLabel)
        self.contentView.addSubview(containerView)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = ViewController()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's all the code you need here to make a custom cell and sticky header:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .purple
        return view
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        50
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        19
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CardCell", for: indexPath) as! CardCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.row)"
        return cell
    }

    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.register(CardCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CardCell")
    }
}


class CardCell: UITableViewCell { }

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = ViewController()
```

Answer (score 0):

To make the header sticky and non-scrollable with the table view you need to take a different UIView above the table view and give the frames of the table just below the UiView.

```
customView = MyCustomView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 50))
self.view.addSubview(customView
```